# Haskell - Access field of a type

Tags: haskell, types

I have created a type in Haskell but I have no idea on how to get one of the fields of my created type. How should I go about? Should I make a function `Book -> String` or something like that?

```
import Data.List
import System.IO


type Book = (Int, String, String, String, String, String, String)



bookNew :: Int -> String -> String-> String -> String -> String -> String -> Book
bookNew isbn title author genre date publisher summary =
   (isbn,title,author,genre,date,publisher,summary):: Book 


main = do
   let book = bookNew 1 "title" "author" "genre" "date" "publisher" "summary"
   --Access title of "book" somehow
   return book
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest using records when creating such a large type. Something along the lines of

```
data Book = Book { pages  :: Int
                 , author :: String
                 , title  :: String
                 }
```

at which point, if you ever wanted the author of a book, it is as simple as

```
main = do
  let book = Book 20 "me" "my book"
  putStrLn (author book)
```

which would print the author of your book.

Records essentially create functions that pull out only a single piece of data from your type.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a type synonym, then you have to manually create functions to retrieve every "field" of your `Book` type:

```
getTitle :: Book -> String
getTitle (_, title, _, _, _, _, _) = title
```

I would recommend you to create your own data type using *record syntax* to get such functions for free.

Additionally, when creating such complex type synonyms, you can create other synonyms that represent the individual parts of your main synonym to make clear what the `Book` represents.

```
type Isbn = Int
type Title = String
type Author = String
type Genre = String
type Date = String 
type Publisher = String
type Summary = String

type Book = (Isbn, Title, Author, Genre, Date, Publisher, Summary)
```

Then `getTitle` can have the type `Book -> Title`

Comment: Even better than type synonyms would be to use `newtype` so that `Title`, `Author`, `Genre` etc. cannot be used in place of each other.